# In Redis, what if I set a node to be a slave of another slave node?

Tags: redis

So in the beginning of time, I ran a master node A.

Then, I ran the second node, B, which I then set as the slave of A.

`node B> SLAVEOF A`

So far so good.

Now, what if I ran the third node, C, which is set as the slave of B?

`node C> SLAVEOF B`

From local testing, it seems that while indeed Redis doesn't have a way of resolving such "transitive" definition, it did perform replications successfully. I was able to retrieve the value that I set in A, from both B and C.

Now, is it acceptable to do this for production? And why (or why not)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chained replication (slave of a slave) is supported in Redis and is an accepted deployment in production - here's the reference from https://redis.io/topics/replication:

> - Slaves are able to accept connections from other slaves. Aside from connecting a number of slaves to the same master, slaves can also be connected to other slaves in a cascading-like structure. Since Redis 4.0, all the sub-slaves will receive exactly the same replication stream from the master.